# disable rotate for my widget

Tags: android, android-widget, rotation

i've developed and android widget and i do not want to disable rotatation feature of my widget. so it would be render only portraid never landscape mode.

i tried this code but it disabled rotaion for all applications. i just only concider my widget.

```
    public static void setAutoOrientationEnabled(ContentResolver resolver, boolean enabled) {    
    Settings.System.putInt(resolver, Settings.System.ACCELEROMETER_ROTATION, enabled ? 1 : 0);
}
```

how can i make it?

thanks

Comment: sorry for typo "...widget and i do not want to disable"  must be "...widget and i want to disable". why i want to disable roation is, i am paint the widget and it is not repainted when rotation occurs till i click any button on it.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a service and register it to the CONFIGURATION_CHANGED event, like this

```
public class MyService extends Service {


@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    BroadcastReceiver bReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            refreshWidget();  // Code to refresh the widget
        }
    };

    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_CONFIGURATION_CHANGED);
    registerReceiver(bReceiver, intentFilter);
```

Comment: but it will consume the battery, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `accelerometer_rotation` for toggle device rotation:

```
String str = Settings.System.getString(paramContext.getContentResolver(), "accelerometer_rotation");
if (str.equals("0"))
      {
        Settings.System.putString(paramContext.getContentResolver(), "accelerometer_rotation", "1");
      }
if (!str.equals("1"))
      Settings.System.putString(paramContext.getContentResolver(), "accelerometer_rotation", "0");
}
```

In manifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
```

Comment: but like this kind of changing effects all applications. i do not want to effect other applications, i just want to disable rotation for only my application.